# A BIG bug of VC++? Why does initializer-list not value-initialize a struct?

Tags: c++, c++11, initialization, aggregate, initializer-list

The C++11 standard 8.5.4.3 says:

"If the initializer list has no elements and T is a class type with a default constructor, the object is value-initialized."

```
struct A
{
    int get() { return i; }

private:
    int i;
};

int main()
{
    A a = {};

    int n = a.get();
    cout << n << endl;
    // n is a random number rather than 0

    return 0;
}
```

Is this a bug of VC++? My VC++ is the latest Nov 2012 CTP.

Comment: The compiler optimization should not break the provision of the C++ standard. So I think this has nothing to do with optimization.

Comment: @KillianDS, please review my revised post

Comment: What is printed if you add `std::cout << n << std::endl;`?

Comment: It printed out 0xCCCCCCCC.

Comment: I get a similar behavior with g++ 4.6.3, but as far as I can tell, that behavior is wrong.  The situation you have seems to be the second case of section 8.5.7, which indicates that zero-initialization will happen.

Comment: 0xCCCCCCCC is the default value in VC++ in debug build for a lot of variables. Does it change every time you compile? Does it change if you build in Release mode?

Comment: It's a random value. I am sure that the struct is not initialized.

Answer (score 3):

Value-initialization of a non-aggregate class type is covered by 8.5p8.  In your case the (non-union) class has an implicitly-declared defaulted default no-parameter constructor (12.1p5), which is not deleted and is trivial (ibid).  Thus the second bullet of 8.5p8 applies:

> — if `T` is a (possibly cv-qualified) non-union class type without a user-provided or deleted default constructor, then the object is zero-initialized and, if `T` has a non-trivial default constructor, default-initialized;

So `A` should be zero-initialized, and the program should print `0`.

On the following program:

```
struct A { int get() { return i; } private: int i; };
#include <iostream>
int main() {
    char c[sizeof(A)];
    new (c) int{42};
    std::cout << (new (c) A{})->get() << '\n';
}
```

gcc-4.7.2 correctly outputs `0`; gcc-4.6.3 incorrectly outputs `42`; clang-3.0 goes absolutely crazy and outputs garbage (e.g. `574874232`).

Comment: Since when does zero- or default-initialising a class touch any otherwise-uninitialised members?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit at least since C++11 **[dcl.init]** /5: "*[...] — if T is a (possibly cv-qualified) non-union class type, each non-static data member and each base-class
subobject is zero-initialized and padding is initialized to zero bits; [...]*"